# Delete a image from InternalStorage using ImagePath

Tags: android, image, android-studio, delete-file, android-storage

I am working with Android version 10.
I have enabled Permissions to Read & Write Storage
Device Name : Poco F1

Scenario: I have to capture a screenshot of the current layout and save it to internalStorage and preview that image to the user. Here users have an option to delete the image.

Here are the codes I am using to save & delete

Saving a screenshot:

```
//I will pass the bitmap here
fun saveBitmapToInternalStorage(bitmap: Bitmap?) {
    bitmap?.let {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            saveBitmapToOlderDevice(it)
        } else {

            saveBitmapToNewerDevice(it)
        }
    }
}





//This method is to save image to newerdevice >= Q
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun saveBitmapToNewerDevice(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    val uri = generateUri()
    context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri ?: return).use { outputStream ->
        outputStream?.let {
            writeBitmapToJpeg(bitmap, outputStream, uri.toString())
        }
    }
}





//This is to generate the URI.
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun generateUri(): Uri? {
    val dateFormat = getDateFormat()
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "${dateFormat}.jpg")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/${context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)}")
    }
    return context.contentResolver.insert(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        contentValues
    )
}





// To save images to olderDevice
private fun saveBitmapToOlderDevice(bmp: Bitmap) {
    val filename = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)?.absolutePath +
            "/${context.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)}/${getDateFormat()}.jpg"
    createDirectory(filename)
    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(filename)

    writeBitmapToJpeg(bmp, outputStream, filename)
}





//This method is to save the image to InternalStorage
private fun writeBitmapToJpeg(bmp: Bitmap, outputStream: OutputStream, imagePath: String) {
    try {
        val outputData = ByteArrayOutputStream()

        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputData)
        outputData.writeTo(outputStream)

        outputStream.flush()
        outputStream.close()

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        showBitmapWriteErrorMessage()
    }
}
```

I save the path while storing the image in internalStorgae
the path looks like

/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TGP AR/20211011142001.jpg
and i pass this path into below method

To delete the image :

```
private fun deleteImage(imagePath: String) {
    val file = File(imagePath)
    file.delete()
}
```

file.exists() is returning true.
file.delete() is returning false.

I think, there might be two different ways to delete ( > & < Q ).
Please help me

Comment: `deleteImage(imagePath` Which path did you use on modern device and where did you get it from? You have no path. You have an uri from insert(). Also try file.canWrite() and file.canRead().

Comment: @blackapps
After saving the image to Storage, I pass it back to view. While the user performs delete,

I use that path and pass it to deleteImage(imagePath : String)

usually, the path looks like

/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TGP AR/20211011142001.jpg

Comment: file.canWrite() and file.canRead is returning false

Comment: As said before: you have no path. You have an uri. Tell where you get that path from on Q+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the image by modifying your method to the following:

```kotlin
private fun deleteImage(imagePath: Uri) { 
    getContentResolver().delete(imagePath, null, null)
}
```

Then pass the `Uri` created in `generateUri()` to delete the file.